# How to create data categories in sql query?

Tags: sql, oracle

Mt table has 3 columns:

```
user_id, start_time, end_time
```

I want to write a SQL query which can return it in the form of

```
Time Spent  Users
 0-30 sec      4   
30-60 sec     20
 1- 5 min      1
 5-30 min      0
30-60 min      0
60+   min      0
```

Category name 'a - b'  contains all values t, with `a <= t < b`.
I can keep the time spent categories fixed.

My data:

```
user_id  start_time                      end_time
    230  08-NOV-15 09.13.42.000000000 PM 08-NOV-15 09.13.42.000000000 PM 
    231  08-NOV-15 11.53.32.000000000 PM 08-NOV-15 11.54.16.000000000 PM
```

Please advise if can be done with a single Oracle SQL query

Comment: Describe current data, e.g. column names and purpose.

Comment: I already provided column names.  Trying to find out number of users spent time slabs

Comment: I think a CASE expression will be useful http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/expressions004.htm#SQLRF20037

Comment: @jahrl: I don't understand your comment: column names , data and sample output is in the OP. So what else do you think is necessary to describe the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't provided any of your own attempts to solve the mystery, I'm just going to give you some steps, that combined should give you the expected result.

- **Step 1:** Calculate accurate time spent for each entry (end_time - start_time).
- **Step 2:** Explicitly define your grouping values to count users that belong to particular group. You can achieve this using `CASE` statement.
- **Step 3:** Add `GROUP BY` statement, to group results by your defined strings in Step 2.
- **Step 4:** Aggregate `user_id` column with `count()` to get your result.

If you have any questions considering the above, feel free to drop them.

Also, please make sure that your time ranges don't overlap, as they do in your question. That would yield odd results.

Comment: "make sure that your time ranges don't overlap" I don't understand ththis? why should ranges not overlap? Why do you think the two ranges of his sample data do overlap, what is a point in time the have in common?

Comment: I see now, you are talking about the categories.

Answer (score 2):

To start with, you have time ranges of different lengths and you want them shown, no matter whether there are entries matching or not. So the first task is: Create rows for these ranges. Then outer-join your table's records and count.

To get a time difference, you'd subtract one datetime from the other. This gives you days or fractions thereof. Multiply with 24 to get hours, with 24x60 to get minutes or 24x60x60 to get seconds. This only works with the data type DATE, however, so if you have TIMESTAMP instead, you must first cast it to DATE (or you'd have to work with intervals instead).

```
select c.category as time_spent, count(user_id) as users
from
(
  select '0-30 sec' as category, 0 as min_secs, 30 as max_secs, 1 as sortkey from dual
  union all
  select '30-60 sec' as category, 30 as min_secs, 60 as max_secs, 2 as sortkey from dual
  union all
  select '1-5 min' as category, 60 as min_secs, 300 as max_secs, 3 as sortkey from dual
  union all
  select '5-30 min' as category, 300 as min_secs, 1800 as max_secs, 4 as sortkey from dual
  union all
  select '30-60 min' as category, 1800 as min_secs,3600 as max_secs, 5 as sortkey from dual
  union all
  select '60min+' as category, 3600 as min_secs, null as max_secs, 6 as sortkey from dual
) c
left join mytable m 
  on  ((cast(m.end_time as date) - cast(m.start_time as date)) * 24*60*60  
        >= c.min_secs or c.min_secs is null)
  and ((cast(m.end_time as date) - cast(m.start_time as date)) * 24*60*60 
        <= c.max_secs or c.max_secs is null)
group by c.category
order by min(c.sortkey);
```

SQL fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a581be/4

As Consider Me already mentioned: your ranges overlap. So a time spent of 30 seconds falls both in category '0-30 sec' and  '30-60 sec' of course. This is no problem and can even be desired, but you should be aware of it.

Comment: this one fails with ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

Comment: Hi, sorry, I had some errors in my query and I thought subtracting timestamps from each other would result in a number just like with dates, but this is not the case - it results in an interval instead. Obviously your start_time and end_time are timestamps and so you got the error. I've corrected my query.